# Subscribing custom topic in ros-mobile

Tags: android, gps, drone, px4, subscribers

I am using [px4-sitl](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/sim_gazebo_gz/) and [mavros](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros) for UAV simulation in ros noetic and try to teleopt the drone using [ros-mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schneewittchen.rosandroid&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1). what I noted mavros has its own message type defined like

```
mubashir@mubashir:~$ rostopic list | grep gps
/mavros/fake_gps/mocap/tf
/mavros/global_position/raw/gps_vel
/mavros/gps_input/gps_input
/mavros/gps_rtk/rtk_baseline
/mavros/gps_rtk/send_rtcm
/mavros/gpsstatus/gps1/raw
/mavros/gpsstatus/gps1/rtk
/mavros/gpsstatus/gps2/raw
/mavros/gpsstatus/gps2/rtk
/mavros/hil/gps
```

if I do

```
mubashir@mubashir:~$ rostopic info /mavros/gpsstatus/gps1/raw
Type: mavros_msgs/GPSRAW

Publishers: 
 * /mavros (http://mubashir:36045/)

Subscribers: None
```

the message type is `mavros_msgs/GPSRAW` and when I add a widget [image: widget]

in ros-mobile for GPS it is only Subscribing `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` but my custom message for GPS is `mavros_msgs/GPSRAW` how can I add a custom subscriber here which subscribes to `mavros_msgs/GPSRAW`